# Setting up Vapor and MongoKitten

Tags: swift, mongodb, heroku, atlassian-sourcetree, vapor

After successfully deploying on localhost (0.0.0.0:8080)
While I pushed the code to git for heroku, 
I am getting error on heroku.

```
Cannot connect to MongoDB
Process exited with status 0
```

Inside package file I added

```
dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten.git", majorVersion: 3)
    ],
```

Inside main.swift the program exists on this line

```
let mongoDatabase = try Database(mongoURL: "mongodb://localhost/mydatabase")
```

Additional info: I believe that on commit there is something which is left out by the SourceTree.
As the same code is also not working after checkout on a different machine. And the code is compiling perfect.

Comment: i think you need to change the mongoURL

Comment: kindly also suggest change to... ?

Comment: your mongodb hoster can tell you this. if it is a service from heroku then in your heroku dashbard

Comment: it should be like: `heroku config:set` and `MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://username:password@ds01316.mlab.com:1316/food` (see https://forum.freecodecamp.com/t/guide-for-using-mongodb-and-deploying-to-heroku/19347 )

Comment: I followed this tutorial... https://medium.com/@joannis.orlandos/using-mongokitten-vapor-for-your-applications-24dbac2f5dd9#.olmn8iobo

Comment: here is an other one. look for the section deploy to server and where you find a DATABASE_URL - it should be the same like with postgreshttp://126kr.com/article/16mwow22r9

Comment: OK thanks. trying them

Comment: also a video https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-deploying-to-heroku-with-postgresql

Comment: you have the name of the mongodb url? ( not your personal url) so i can update my answer with the name

Comment: this line i mean for your mongodb setting `--config:postgresql.url=$DATABASE_URL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an info how to get the DATABASE_URL for postgres  but it shold be the same for mongo DB:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

after some minits preparation:

```
heroku config
```

there shold be the url

in your `Procfile` (you created with `vapor init`) you can add the db url:

our text editor and update it so that looks like the below.

```
web: App --env=production --workdir="./"
web: App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=$PORT --config:postgresql.url=$DATABASE_URL
```

this is the db url we add `--config:postgresql.url=$DATABASE_URL`

Save `Procfile` and type `git push heroku master`

after some time it should working.

you should change the name `postgresql.url` to your mongo db confog name (depending which mongo addon you use)